# Apply CSS rules if element isn't a child of other element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do the following.
I have a paragraph with multiple colors.

```html
<p>Hello <span class="red">Wo<span class="blue">rld</span></span>, <span class="blue">how are you</span></p>
```

```css
.blue
{
    color: blue;
}

.red
{
    color: red;
}
```

I need that .blue doesn't apply if it is in red.
How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, and Welcome, your question is ambiguous, please check this before asking. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you @AbedPutra for warning me, I'll make sure to write better questions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup seems a bit iffy to me, it would be simpler to just not apply one color inside another.

But if your use case requires it...

You can use the negation pseudo-class on the direct parent:

```css
:not(.red) > .blue {
  color: blue;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello <span class="red">Wo<span class="blue">rld</span></span>, <span class="blue">how are you</span></p>
```

Or you can require that the direct parent is a paragraph:

```css
p > .blue {
  color: blue;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello <span class="red">Wo<span class="blue">rld</span></span>, <span class="blue">how are you</span></p>
```

Comment: Thank you! I went for the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class blue from the span containing "rld"

```
<p>Hello <span class="red">Wo<span>rld</span></span>, <span class="blue">how are you</span></p>
```

Comment: While I would have done that, it's actually because I have a PHP Script that changes colors when it matches characters, and I had a conflict like an example in my post.